# How to pull a list with in a list by matching one value in an external list, in Python?

Tags: python, list, loops, indexing, linked-list

My data is a large (linked) list, that is made up of smaller lists (7500+).  And within these smaller lists exists another list with strings as their value. List A <-- List B's <-- List C (names).

```
List_A = [['123', 'Hello World', '2020', ['john', 'mike', 'edgar'], 'N'],
          ['124', 'Hello Universe', '2021', ['harold', 'jessica', 'ashley'], 'Y'],
          ['125', 'Hello Milkyway', '2020', ['maria', 'tessa', 'rodrigo'], 'N']]

List_A.nodeat(0).value[3]
>>>> ['john', 'mike', 'edgar']

Outside this large list, I've created a string split list of names:
List_Outside = ['mike', 'maria'].
```

I want to create a new list (List_A_2) of only List B's that have at least one matching name from List_Outside in List C.

So List_A_2 would look like:

```
List_A_2 = [['123', 'Hello World', '2020', ['john', 'mike', 'edgar'], 'N'],
           ['125', 'Hello Milkyway', '2020', ['maria', 'tessa', 'rodrigo'], 'N']]
```

Of course I would like this to be applicable for 7500+ lists so I would need to use indexes in a for loop. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `any()` to filter the list:

```py
List_A_2 = [l for l in List_A if any(w in List_Outside for w in l[3])]
print(List_A_2)
```

Prints:

```py
[['123', 'Hello World', '2020', ['john', 'mike', 'edgar'], 'N'], 
['125', 'Hello Milkyway', '2020', ['maria', 'tessa', 'rodrigo'], 'N']]
```